# plain class to implement EventListener

Tags: android, events, interface

I have this class :

public class post2social {

```
public interface socialResult extends EventListener {
    public void responseResult(String val);
}

public socialResult listener;

private String message, name, caption, descr, URL, picture;
private Context c;
private SocialAuthAdapter adapter;

public post2social(Context c, String message, String name, String caption, String descr, String URL, String picture) {
    this.c = c;

    this.message = message;
    this.name = name;
    this.caption = caption;
    this.descr = descr;
    this.URL = URL;
    this.picture = picture;

    adapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());

    try {
        adapter.addConfig(Provider.FACEBOOK, c.getString(R.string.fb1), c.getString(R.string.fb2), null);
        adapter.addConfig(Provider.TWITTER, c.getString(R.string.tw1), c.getString(R.string.tw2), null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex){}
}

private final class MessageListener implements SocialAuthListener<Integer> {
    @Override
    public void onExecute(String provider, Integer t) {
        Integer status = t;
        if (status.intValue() == 200 || status.intValue() == 201 || status.intValue() == 204)
            listener.responseResult("Message posted on " + provider);
}
```

}

where the **listener.responseResult** raise the event, nice!

now, when using this class in an activity, there isnot **setListener** method to s variable!

> post2social s = new post2social(Test.this, "", "", "", "", "", );

tested to implement the EventListener to the class as :

> public class post2social implements EventListener {

again there is no **setListener** method! any clue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to change this line of your code:

```
adapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());
```

to this:

```
adapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(this);
```

when your post2social class implement EventListener, you should pass it to SocailAuthAdapter as Listener.